# How to config var_dump to show result in pre tag

Tags: php, xdebug, var-dump

I have recently updated wampserver from version 3.0 to 3.1 and before the var_dump showed me the results in pre tags, now I have seen the configuration in php.ini and xdebug is installed and configured.

I do not know if someone has already found this problem, thanks for any response.

This is my actual php.ini configuration:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0

xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1 
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1 

xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 2
```

--EDIT--SOLVE--

@RiggsFolly thanks for the interest.

xdebug works fine with php5.6 and 7.0 but when I chage it to 7.1.9 just don't work

So I just downloaded the last xdebug officially version from https://xdebug.org/download.php PHP 7.1 VC14 TS (64 bit) and change the php.ini dll file name, and works again.

Comment: xdebug has been installed and configured in WAMPServer for YEARS

Comment: Are you trying to turn XDEBUG Off?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, maybe the xdebug version in the php7.1.9 folder was for the php7.0, I didn't test it just update it, I edit the question already.